# How can I intercept rails's template rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, rendering

I have an application which serves more than one website.
Similar to Stack Exchange, these several sites behave very similarly to each other.

Given the following views directory structure:

```
views/
  shared/users/index.html.erb
  app1/users/index.html.erb
  app2/users/
```

How can I re-write the default template rendering in Rails so that

- when App1's UsersController#index is called, it renders app1/users/index.html.erb
- when App2's UsersController#index is called, it realises there is no index.html.erb template so for checks shared/users/index.html.erb before raising the missing template error

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know you already accepted an answer for this, but I don't think you need to create your own template resolver.

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to "theme" your views depending on some aspect of the current state of the app. I have done the same thing previously using this dandy little controller method:

```
prepend_view_path "app/views/#{current_app_code}"
```

Throw this in a before_filter in your application controller, and all your controllers will obey:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :prepend_view_paths

  def prepend_view_paths
    prepend_view_path "app/views/#{current_app_code}"
  end

end
```

Now rails will first look for "app/views/app1/users/index.html.erb" when "/users" is requested if "app1" is the current app.

If it doesn't find it there, it rolls back to the default location at "app/views/users/index.html.erb".

Hope this gives you another alternative.

Comment: Please note that "current_app_code" is something you have to create. I just used it as an example.

Comment: Hi

Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not sure this will work because the default location is not simply /views/users but views/shared/users

Comment: you can add that too if you like. The method accepts an array: 

prepend_view_path(["views/default", "views/custom"])

Comment: I still can't get this to work. This method sends the current path prefix (eg. app1/users/). Using this approach it looks for /views/shared/app1/users and not /views/shared/users. I have to remove the current prefix "app1" which is what I did in my resolver.

Comment: Turns out I didn't need to write my own resolver here... thanks!

Comment: Wow, I read this answer, but didn't read it carefully enough. `If it doesn't find it there, it rolls back to the default location at "app/views/users/index.html.erb".` That's fantastic! I spent half an hour trying to do that myself.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you'll have to code your own Template Resolver.
Perhaps [this blog post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/04/default-views-in-rails-3-0-with-custom-resolvers/) can help.

Comment: Thanks!

I originally went with alias method chaining the render method but this seems to be less resource intensive! :)