# Multiple inheritance in Ruby ... Inheriting from multiple controller classes.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multiple-inheritance

I have a Rails app. All my controllers inherit from a `BaseController` that inherits from the `ApplicationController::Base` This is for organization of my partials into separate namespaces. It works great.

Here is the problem.

I am trying to use the Devise gem, but the `Devise::SessionsController` can't find my partials, which are stored in a folder named Base. My solution was to create a local controller that inherited from `Devise::SessionsController` like this:

```
module Account
  class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  end
end
```

The problem is that the this local `SessionsController` still needs to inherit from my `BaseController` so it can find my partials. Make sense?

BaseController code:

```
module Account
  class BaseController < ApplicationController
  end
end
```

ApplicationController code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

end
```

I've been reading about mixins, but can't see how I can use mixins to solve this problem, because I don't have any methods to import from the class ...

Comment: `can't find my partials` => http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/ViewPaths/ClassMethods.html#method-i-prepend_view_path

Comment: Can you give an example of how I would use this?

Comment: def prepend_view_path(path)
  self._view_paths = ActionView::PathSet.new(Array(path) + view_paths)
end  Does this go in the controller that inherits from Devise::SessionsController?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055319/how-can-i-intercept-railss-template-rendering

Comment: Thanks, so now I have prepend_view_path "app/views/" do you know what I would have to put after views/ to specify that I want it to look in the views namespace with the same name as the current controller namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is simply to make the path to your partials more explicit. So in my example, in my Application layout file I changed the partial path from this:

```
<%= render "menu" %>
```

to this:

```
<%= render "account/base/menu" %>
```

This works because rails looks for the partial in the regular places, but can't find it and throws an error. Specifying exactly where the partial can be found when putting the partial into your HTML solves the problem of Rails or any gems from not knowing where your partials are.