# Rails - Multiple Views(admin, regular) from same action(index)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 versions of an same index page which display a list of products.
Regular view - Displays List
Admin view - Displays List with options to edit, delete etc.

The index action just makes the database query and returns that instance variable.
Currently, I have the same index action for rendering the index page. I want to reuse the index action form product into the admin controller.

```
def index
    @products = Product.all
end
```

routes:

```
/product/index  => product#index

/admin/product/index  => product#index
```

I tried the prepend_view_path technique given [here | [How can I intercept rails's template rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055319/how-can-i-intercept-railss-template-rendering]), but then this always ends up rendering the admin/product/index.html.erb file in both cases.

I want the Product#index controller#action to render:

> /index.html.erb for /product/index

and

> /admin/product/index.html.erb for /admin/product/index

Can someone help me with how this could be done in an elegant way instead of just writing the same action for admin controller class and product controller class.

PS: I'm just one week into ruby and ruby on rails. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within your controllers, just render view you want to serve for user, I mean:

```
ProductsController
def index
  # ...
  render 'index'
end

Admin::ProductsController
def index
  # ...
  render 'products/index'
end
```

Comment: Yeah but if I create 2 separate controller actions then, the #... part you added would need to be replicated in both actions

Comment: Explain your controllers hierarchy then. `ProductsController` is the ancestor or descendant of `Admin::ProductsController`?

Comment: ProductsController and AdminController are different but I want to use the index action of ProductsController  in AdminController  because the method is exactly the same

Comment: Actually I've added a hack to the admin url by adding a variable. I might just separate it out.

Comment: You have various method to achieve that. If any of these controllers is descendant of another, then within descendant index action you may call super, e.g: `def index; super; end`. If not, you can create some helper method within ancestor controller (e.g. `ApplicationController`), put there all logic and use within `index` method of descendants. You can create a module and include it into your controllers. Finally, it looks like your controllers structure should look like `ProductsController < Admin::ProductsController` (or the opposite - it depends which one is ancestor of another).

Answer (score 2):

There is a Mistake in routes .

/product/index  => product#index

/admin/product/index  => product#index

Both pointing to the same contoller names as product.

I would suggest these routes

```
resources  :admin do 
  resources :product do 
  end
end

resources :product do 
end
```

By doing so you make sure that you have two products Controller.
 One with Admin::ProductController
Second ProductController

admin_product_path for admin view
product_path for normal view

Answer (score 0):

I faced this challenge when working on a **Rails 6** application.

I had two types of users: **Customers** and **Admins**. I was using the **Devise** gem for authentication. I wanted the **Products** views for the **Customer** to be different from the **Admins** View.

I already had an `app/controllers/admins` directory in the **controllers** for the **Devise** configuration for **Admins**.

**Here's how I did it**:

First, define a new **route** for the Admins `products` view using the `admins` namespace.

```
namespace :admins do
  resources :products do
  end
end
```

**Note**: This will affect the Paths/URLs for the Admins. Say, the `products_path` will not be `admins_products_path`.

Then, in the **controllers** add the `products_controller.rb` to the `app/controllers/admins` directory:

```
class Admins::ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to admins_product_path(@product), notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: admins_product_path(@product) }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to admins_product_path(@product), notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: admins_product_path(@product) }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to admins_products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :sku, :short_description, :full_description)
    end
end
```

**Note**: Take note of the ProductsController namespacing using the Admins Module and the modified paths in the `create`, `update` and `destroy` actions od the

And finally, in the **views**, add the views associated with the Admins Products in the `app/views/admins/products` directory.

**Note**: You may have to modify the paths in the views to correspond with the routes for the admins products. Say, the `show` view for **admins products** will be `admins_product_path(product)` and not `product` or `product_path(product)`.

There is a cleaner approach using the [cells](https://trailblazer.to/2.0/gems/cells/) gem. This eliminates the need to duplicate code, and it comes in handy when you need to define views for up to 3 or more roles. You can read up more about how to use it here: [Object-Oriented Views in Rails](https://datarockets.com/blog/object-oriented-views-in-rails/).

That's all.

**I hope this helps**